# What is java instance?

Tags: java

In the real world, you'll often find many individual objects all of the same kind. There may be thousands of other bicycles in existence, all of the same make and model. Each bicycle was built from the same set of blueprints and therefore contains the same components. In object-oriented terms, we say that your bicycle is an instance of the class of objects known as bicycles. A class is the blueprint from which individual objects are created.

Can anyone explain the fourth line of this para..Thank You.

Comment: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Instance means, the output of blueprint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you and a friend have the same model of bicycle, even though they **look** the same and **act** the same, they are each their own **instance** of a bicycle.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubts..now i understands what it mean.Sorry for the silly question,I know the question marked a negative impression but i had no choice..Thanks a lot.

Comment: Their own instance of the bicycle, probably with a unique serial number engraved into it.

Comment: No problem @ChaoAbhishekPhukan. Please mark the answer as accepted if it was a correct answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have an abstract idea, what a bicycle is, but you have the object your bicycle. This certain object is in Java an instance, while the pure abstract idea or concept of a bicycle your class is.